# Query for a collection of parent entities returns always only 1 element of child entity

Tags: hibernate, jpa, parent-child, one-to-many

I have the following entities:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "request")
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@Component
public class Request {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", columnDefinition = "varchar(64)")
    private String id;

    ... 
    
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="request")
    private Set<RequestError> error;
    ...
```

and

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "edepot_request_error")
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class RequestError implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "request_error_id_seq", sequenceName =            "request_error_id_seq", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "request_error_id_seq")

    @JoinColumn(name="idempotencykey")
    private String idempotencyKey;

   @ManyToOne(targetEntity=Request.class)
   private Request request;

   ...
```

When trying to do a query like for example :

```
EntityManager entityManager = emf.createEntityManager();
        //EntityGraph entityGraph = entityManager.getEntityGraph("request-entity-graph");

        String requestSql= "SELECT req FROM Request req";

        List<Request> qryResultRequests = entityManager.createQuery(requestSql, Request.class)
                .getResultList();
```

I always get the correct collection of parent records, but I always get a child collection of 1 error (when the child table contains multiple errors for a parent).
I did search through multiple questions here on the forum and I did try some of the suggestions :

- use entitygraph
- use left join fetch as explained in [https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-onetomany-association-with-jpa-and-hibernate/](mapping one-to-many association)
- use mappedBy, remove mappedBy

The collection of parents returned is correct, though the `List<Request>` contain always only 1 error from the collection of childs for a given parent (that should contains multiple errors).

The error table and request table are filled up independently from each other in our application and the query is only a select (read) query to get in a console the request records with underneath the errors that were generated for a request.
The idea is to load the child entities via the parent entity
What do I miss or what am Ì doing wrong?

Comment: This is standard JPA stuff, so you shouldn't need workarounds to get requests with the full list of RequestError instances within the error collection. You are using a Set though - check that you haven't used some equality/hashcode implementation on your entity that makes them all look the same. Don't use @Data or other annotations that generate those methods for you unless you are certain you know what is generated and what it means to your application - they are likely wrong for JPA entities which should be defined by their IDs, not mutable fields.

Comment: You also cannot have a @JoinColumn definition on a basic mapping (idempotencyKey). What are you trying to map with that?  Remove that with a column, remove the equals/hashcode implementations, and if that doesn't work, show the SQL generated for your query and verify that it returns multiple RequestError per Request and we can help tell what might be going wrong.